# Why did the U.S. forced Japan to stop its government subsidized VLSI project while it also had its own government subsidized VLSI project?

Tags: united-states, international, japan

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLSI_Project

> On Japan's side, the government was concerned about a negative impact
>   on its relationship with the United States with regard to both
>   national security and exports. Concessions were made mainly in two
>   ways. First, the state ended its role in promoting national R&D
>   projects. **For example, the very large-scale integrated circuit
>   project was immediately closed down in 1980.**

How did Japan's R&D project differ from other R&D project from other countries and was the decision to force Japan to close down its project based on a legal basis, or was it a form of abuse of power?